# What function in JavaScript should I use for this exercise?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on JavaScript exercise and have hit a roadblock on how to go about this question: I have sourced some data from an API, Im looking to loop over the objects and categorize them into sections based on each items assigned property ‘type’ and then sort the items by certain key in the objects.

Thank you.

```
const items = ListItems.map((value) => {
  return value.type >= "list";
});

console.log(items)

//This gave me response in the console :
[false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, true]

0: false

1: true

2: false

3: false

4: false

5: false

6: false

7: false

8: true

9: false

10: false

11: false

12: false

13: false

14: true
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: This definitely needs more info. What did you tried so far ? Can we see some code ?

Comment: hi, welcome on stackoverflow ; please update your post with what you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing service. You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to write a "good" question. voting for closing post as it's off-topic without any more details and code you have tried

Comment: Thank you for responding; never asked a question here - my first so I apologize for not putting it across in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` to create an object that holds a container for each type. Then use `sort` to sort each of the containers afterwards:

```js
var listItems = [
  {type: "Dog", value: 5},
  {type: "Cat", value: 7},
  {type: "Fox", value: 2},
  {type: "Dog", value: 3},
  {type: "Fox", value: 9}, 
  {type: "Cat", value: 3},
  {type: "Fox", value: 6}
];

// create an object that holds a container for each type
var types = listItems.reduce(function(containers, obj) {
  (containers[obj.type] = containers[obj.type] || []).push(obj); 
  return containers;
}, {});

// sort each container of the Types-object 
// by comparing the value property of each object
Object.keys(types).forEach(function(key) {
  types[key].sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; });
});
 
console.log(types);
```